# Do I need a comma in "Тут есть, над чем подумать"?

Tags: пунктуация

Do I need a comma in "Тут есть, над чем подумать"? And can anyone parse this sentence for me, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comma is not needed. *Над чем подумать* is the subject of the sentence, it's a verbal phrase, an infinitive with an indirect object. The verb *есть* agrees with it, it's singular, "Тут" is a predicative (I have some doubts about "Тут", it can be an adverbial modifier of place).