# Do I need a comma in "Хорошо, что я прочитал всю статью"?

Tags: пунктуация

I am not sure if I need a comma in "Хорошо, что я прочитал всю статью"? Can anyone shed some light here, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Хорошо* is an impersonal sentence and it is a part of a complex sentence. You definitely need a comma before *что*.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are some exceptions, in general you always need a comma before "что".

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! Usually we prefer longer and more elaborated answers to short answers. If you can improve your answer by adding detail, context, examples, and backing up with references, this would increase your answer's quality. Poor answers risk being down-voted and subsequently removed.

Comment: @Varvara: `Что` can be pronoun (`Я понял, что вы имели в виду`) =what in English, or conjunction (`Он сказал, что не придет`) =that in English. In both cases it is preceded by comma because `что` introduces a subordinate clause. But can you elaborate on exceptions which you mentioned?

Comment: Example of exeptions (very rare): Запятая не ставится перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в составе неразложимых сочетаний: хватать **что** подвернется, говорить **что** в ум взбредет, добиваться во **что** бы то ни стало, делай **что** хочешь, бери **что** нравится, есть **что** дают, будь **что** будет, кричит **что** есть мочи, выдумывали кто во **что** горазд, достать **что** нужно (но: достать всё, **что** нужно), черт знает **что** у них творится, городить черт знает **что**, ты **что** хочешь думай. Данное правило основано на том, что фразеологические обороты не образуют прид

Comment: I didn't ask for these exceptions in my question. I guess you were answering to farfareast's comment.

Comment: Tltuxilya made a valid point, you need to use comma everywhere but in these cases. So it answers your question too

Comment: @farfareast, as for exceptions, you don't have to use comma in "потому что" if the meaning is "because". But use comma before "потому" in this case.

Comment: I guess also comma is not used when there is no subordinate clause. F.e. Уж не знаю что вам и сказать.

Comment: Не могу согласиться с тем, что запятая не ставится **только** во фразеологических оборотах. Смотрите один из предыдущих вопросов от brilliant ["Тут есть над чем подумать"](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/1580/496) - запятая не ставится. _Чем_ здесь - это творительный падеж от _что_. _Что_ в винительном падеже будет тоже _что_. Так что во всех фразах с _что_ в винительном падеже, где **не** вводится придаточное предложение, запятая ставиться не будет. Например: "Тут есть что посмотреть".

Comment: @brilliant: I was hinting at the fact that if there are rules for exceptions they are not really exceptions any more. Something like this. See my previous comment. Just wanted to suggest improvements to Varvara's answer, it seemed too short. Looks like I did not made myself clear. :-(

Comment: @farfareast - You DID make yourself perfectly clear. Thank you.

Comment: @v'-5o-1's73- "Tltuxilya made a valid point, you need to use comma everywhere but in these cases. So it answers your question too" - No, it doesn't as my question is about one specific case, which is not included in all the cases brought up by Tltuxilya.

Comment: @brilliant, you don't have any math background, do you?

Comment: @v'-5o-1's73- No. Now, please enlighten me how math has anything to do with it.

Comment: @brilliant, well the answer that was given covered all situations including the one from your question, thus you answer was addressed too. Although the answer wasn't specific for you particular case one with some math intuition could easily deduct it from there. From what you said you think it wasn't covered which is something that confuses me. He said: you need to use comma everywhere, but in the following cases. Your case wasn't there. So your case isn't an exception. So you should use comma. The question remains however whether the original statement was true. We assume it was.

Comment: @v'-5o-1's73- "He said: you need to use comma everywhere, but in the following cases..." - Really?! Where did he say that?! From what I can see in his comment, he said only "Example of exceptions". The very word "example" implies that there could be some other kinds of possible exceptions. "Example of exceptions" doesn't mean "full list of exceptions". You seem to have added your own meaning to his words.